# MutationObserver keeps looping through each item and creating redundant buttons in TamperMonkey Script

Tags: javascript, java, tampermonkey, mutation-observers, mutation

I am working on a script for use with Tampermonkey, and it is almost finished, but I keep running into an issue with the mutationobserver looping through each specified item on the page. The page will have varying numbers of "input-money-group" items, and every time the script loads I need it to add buttons to the page when it sees that input box loaded.

However, instead of adding the buttons once, it is adding the buttons for each iteration of finding that box, so I need to limit it to running that inner function only one time. Here is the code.

```
const isAddPage = window.location.hash === '#/p=add' || window.location.hash === '#/add',
        {
            loader,
            popup,
            buttons,
            getCurrentTab
        } = pricer;

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        for (const mutation of mutations) {
            for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                if (node.classList && node.classList.contains('input-money-group')) {

                    console.log('its working');
                    // Create all elements & update tab.
                    if (isAddPage) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            getCurrentTab();
                            loader.build();
                            popup.build();
                            buttons.build();
                            observer.disconnect();
                        }, 250);
                      }

                }
            }
        }
    })

    const wrapper = document.querySelector('#bazaarroot')
    observer.observe(wrapper, {
        subtree: true,
        childList: true })
```

I have already tried using observer.disconnect(); in varios places and it doesn't stop it from creating redundant buttons.

Comment: I've had issues like this with MutationObserver. I think your issue is possibly with the timing of reattaching too quickly. Try putting the (re-)observe in a setTimeout function?

Comment: I tried adding that in, but depending on how fast the page loads, it still gets through several iterations.